# What is the Jacobi-Anger expansion of $\sin^{[k]} (\theta) $?

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, bessel-functions, trigonometric-sums

[Cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3910272/what-is-the-jacobi-anger-expansion-of-the-kth-functional-iterate-of-the-sine) from MSE.

The Jacobi-Anger [expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion) gives expressions for functional iterates of trigonometric functions in terms of Bessel functions. For instance, we have $$\sin(z \sin(\theta)) = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} J_{2n-1} (z) \sin[(2n-1)\theta] .$$
If we plug in $z=1$, we obtain an expression for $\sin(\sin(\theta)) := \sin^{[2]}(\theta)$. We might call this the second functional iterate of the sine function. Moreover, we have $\sin^{[3]}(\theta) = \sin(\sin(\sin(\theta))) $, and $\sin^{[k]}(\theta)$ is the function in which there are $k-1$ compositions of the sine function with itself (when $k\geq2$).

**Question**: Are Jacobi-Anger expansions for the $k$'th functional iterate -- $\sin^{[k]}(\theta)$ -- also known, for arbitrary $k>2$?

Comment: Isn't this just the Fourier expansion of odd periodic functions such as $\,\sin^{[k]}(\theta)\,$ whose coefficients are certain integrals?

Comment: @Somos Yes, I think so. At least for $k=2$, the two expressions seem to coincide: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877408/fourier-series-sin-sinx

Comment: here is one representation: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4297398/87355

Comment: @CarloBeenakker interesting, thank you. Would be great if the Bessel sum coefficients could be simplified and written in a closed form somehow